# Can anyone explain how to add xml report from SonarQube for java project

Tags: java, spring-boot, sonarqube

Added SonarQube in project, I'm able to get HTML report
by this 
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview Dsonar.issuesReport.html.enable=true

But need XML report, is there any way to do that?

Comment: Provide your code, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no XML report. By the way using scanners to produce "reports" is deprecated in favor of:

- [SonarLint](http://www.sonarlint.org/) on developer box (pre-commit/pre-push check)
- Plugins like [GitHub](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin) (pre merge check)